# How to open telnet port in wireless D-Link router?

Tags: router, telnet

I want to access D-Link DIR-600L wireless router via terminal. Can i do this by opening telnet port. How to open telnet port in wireless routers?

Comment: If the router really supports telnet (or some other remote terminal access), you should be able to find the answer to your question on the user's manual.

Comment: Apparently you can with some kind of hack whether it's advisable or not I don't know http://www.spect.cl/blog/2011/12/d-link-dir-600-command-injection

Comment: As mentioned by quannt you should be able to enable this via the web interface but you should avoid Telnet as it is not secure. SSH is a much better option.

Answer (score 2):

Based in other answer this worked for me:

Login to the web interface.

You can access shell terminal using: `192.168.0.1/shell.asp` where 192.168.0.1 is your IP address of Wi-Fi router.

In the shell terminal you type: `telnetd` and press Apply. **DO NOT USE telnetd.sh.**

Using telnet client in your PC and type `telnet 192.168.0.1` and you can see login prompt.

I was able to update iptables.

This is the telnetd.sh file if anybody wants to know

```
# cat /bin/telnetd.sh 
#!/bin/sh
image_sign=`cat /etc/alpha_config/image_sign`
echo "Start telnetd ..." > /dev/console
mfc_mode=`flash get_hwflag mfc`
if [ $mfc_mode = 1 ]; then
        timeout=" -t 600"
fi
if [ -f "/usr/bin/login" ]; then
        telnetd -l "/usr/bin/login" -u Alphanetworks:$image_sign -i br0 $timeout &
else
        telnetd &
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to the web interface.
2. You can access shell terminal using: `192.168.0.1/shell.asp` where `192.168.0.1` is your IP address of Wi-Fi router.
3. In the shell terminal you type: `telnetd.sh` and press `Apply`.
4. Using telnet client in your PC and type `telnet 192.168.0.1` and you can see login prompt.

But I can’t find any information to login by root. Router say `login incorrect` when I type `root` in login prompt.

Comment: thank, but i think if someone know answer when search this question, i can get the solution in fastest way.

Comment: Try `admin`, else, since it's likely the information would be covered somewhere by an OpenWrt or DD-WRT user, I'd recommend doing some research on OpenWrt and DD-WRT's sites, wikis, or forums if either supports the device, as well as through google.

Comment: use telnetd rather than telnetd.sh

Answer (score -2):

First of all, don't use telnet - just don't if you can avoid it. Buy a copy of Michael W. Lucas ["SSH Mastery 2nd Edition"](https://www.michaelwlucas.com/tools/ssh) (which is actually quite approachable) and read it. **Telnet is not encrypted** (and also has way less functionality than OpenSSH)!

**If you want to use telnet anyway:**

1. Login to the web interface with Your credentials.
2. If you use Windows, open cmd.exe from start. (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Write `telnet <YOUR ROUTERS IP HERE>` e.g. like `telnet 192.168.0.100`
4. Login as `admin` and write Your password.

Your D-Link DIR-600L Router has most likely [many security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/31624/D-link-Dir-600l-Firmware.html?vendor_id=899). Please do the internet community a favor and upgrade to a supported operating system like OpenWRT (which would give you complete SSH also) or by buying a supported router from a reputable manufacturer and keeping it up to date.

I have myself used [OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-600) on a similar device by D-Link. Installing it will probably also be easier than you expect and you will have SSH access and full control also. In OpenWRT, there are serious advances in how your internet connection gets used more efficiently and also regular security fixes (which you should apply). You might also learn something helpful on the way, like **not using telnet** in 2018.

Btw. you will do yourself a favor, if you upgrade to something newer with Gigabit Ethernet Ports, and more RAM (like at least 128 MB). You can have a look, whether OpenWRT folks recommend it beforehand, since those are actually the serious users. The Linksys WRT AC1200 seems to be well supported.

Comment: While you make several good points, your answer has very little to do with what was asked.  Telnet is a feature that needs to die due to it's serious security risks and implications, however @Mmh asked how to enable it, which you didn't even attempt to address.  Might I suggest editing your answer to address that, as well as removing the 1st & 3rd paragraphs?  Without an edit, you're likely going to see more down votes.  If you edit your answer, I'll remove my down vote.

Comment: Thank You for Your time and thought. Please read the question again "I want to access D-Link DIR-600L wireless router via terminal. Can i do this by opening telnet port. [Grammatically, here should be a question mark.]" -> My answer to what the user wants to do is don't, you will hurt yourself and possibly others. Then I offer an overall better solution - SSH and possibly OpenWRT, which also puts you in control of your device. This is what I think the user actually wants.

Comment: Thank you for considering re-wording your answer, my down vote has been removed.